# Changing the constant of a NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

### Background

I'm trying to do a fairly standard NSLayoutConstraint constant update, with both an animated and non-animated option. To give you some background, I have a UIView subclass called ProgressView. Within the ProgressView, there is the Progress Bar UIView. The Progress Bar UIView is connected as a referencing outlet `progressBar` to the ProgressView class. Here's how the fairly simple hierarchy looks within the Storyboard:

[image: Storyboard hierarchy shows Progress Bar within Progress View]

As you might have guessed, I'm building a custom progress bar. The ProgressView UIView is the "track," and the Progress Bar UIView is the "fill." The plan is to use the trailing constraint of the Progress Bar UIView to make changes to the progress.

---

### Existing configuration

The constraints for the Progress Bar UIView are set up to be flush with the superview (Progress View):

[image: Constraints]

The trailing constraint of the Progress Bar UIView is connected to the ProgressView class as a strong outlet: `@IBOutlet var trailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!`.

Within the ProgressView class, there is a `setProgress` function. This function is called from the ViewController which contains the ProgressView. Here's the function with comments explaining how it works:

```
 public func setProgress(_ progress: Double, animationDuration: Double) {

    // Pre-conditions
    guard progress >= 0.0 && progress <= 1.0 && animationDuration >= 0.0 else {
        return
    }

    // Calculate the new constraint constant based on the progress
    let newConstant = CGFloat(1 - progress) * self.bounds.size.width

    // If the update should be made without animation, just make the change and return
    guard animationDuration > 0.0 else {
        trailingConstraint.constant = newConstant            
        return
    }

    // Set the constraint first
    self.trailingConstraint.constant = newConstant

    // Animate!
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}
```

---

### The problem

As you can see, this function can update the progress with and without animation. However, when called from the ViewController, neither works. The trailing constraint constant appears to remain 0, and the progress bar fills the entire track.

[image: Filled bar]

---

### Attempted solutions

I have tried calling `layoutIfNeeded()` and `setNeedsLayout()` in every position and configuration where it makes sense (on both `self` [where `self` is the ProgressView] and on `progressBar`). I have tried putting the code explicitly on the main thread with `DispatchQueue.main.async`. As a ground truth test, I tried connecting the trailingConstraint outlet to the ViewController itself and updating the constant from the `viewDidAppear()` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` methods. Nothing works.

---

### A possible hint in the right direction

Here's the weird part. The progress bar appears filled on the screen, but when I debug the view hierarchy, the progress bar looks correct. The trailingConstraint constant seems to have been set correctly.

[image: Correct bar]

[image: Correct constraints]

I was testing on an iOS 10 device and running Xcode 8.3.3. This issue seems really odd to me, and I'm not quite sure what to do from here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.My problem was solved by changing constant in animation .Try this out:

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) { 
    self.trailingConstraint.constant = newConstant
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Comment: I've tried layoutIfNeeded and constant outside the animation with layoutIfNeeded inside. I've tried constant and layoutIfNeeded inside. None worked unfortunately.

Comment: put this line self.trailingConstraint.constant = newConstant outside the animation block

Comment: are you giving the animation duration of 0.2 sec.Try that out.It is like a kind of hack

Comment: @Dev_Tandel I've tried that. Didn't work unfortunately. In my setProgress method, I also have a non-animated constraint change within the guard. That doesn't work either.

Comment: @Arnav I've tried a hard coded duration value (2 secs). Didn't work. Would 0.2 secs be different?